# Lightswitch: Multi-Tiers .NET and Reactive Programming made easy what's its limit?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm watching the architecture of lightswicth
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Steve-Anonsen-and-John-Rivard-Inside-LightSwitch

I find it pretty impressive it has nothing to do with ugly RAD like VB6 it is based on the most advanced concepts and frameworks. I agree with them that most domain developers are very good at domain level but not good at system level so lightswitch compensates for this. But it's so much advanced that even non-programmers but advanced users will be able to build a Multi-Tiers .NET and Reactive Programming system without even realizing it (that's what Forrester Research thinks http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/desmond-file/2010/08/lightswitch-questions-with-jeffrey-hammond.aspx).

So are there any disadvantages for choosing lightswicth technology ?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem I see is breaking out of the box on the UI side. If you have specific requirements that does not fit the LightSwitch model. If you need a navigation scheme that does not match LightSwitch page based with automatically layouted controls.
I would not think of creating a CAD like UI in LightSwitch. But regular LOB data view/update applications would be fine.
I would also would not create a chat type application in LightSwitch. But that might just be my lack of imagination and understanding of LightSwitch.

On the server side there seems to be enough hooking points to make it extensible for most needs. If you can not / don't want to solve it inside LightSwitch you can easly make a WCF call to another service.

Comment: As far as I can see you can customize LightSwitch including and above all UI since UI is really part of Business App ? LigthSwitch is about automating System Infrastructure side so for me the problem would be more on that side.

Comment: LightSwitch allows you to completely customize the UI. You can create your own Shell and custom Silverlight controls. This article walks through an example with code: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/10/LightSwitch-Student-Information-System-Part-3-Custom-Controls.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that terminology, what LOB means?

Comment: @pabben LOB = [Line Of Business](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_business), that is mostly internal applications on companies.